# Running postman scripts in bamboo CI server

Tags: continuous-integration, postman, bamboo, newman

my requirement is to run postman scripts in bamboo. We have a repository for the collection.json, however, as my environment file has some sensitive data like `client_id`, `secret_id`, `username`, `password` etc I can't push it to my repo.

Please advise me how can I run my collections in bamboo using Newman.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize your environmental variables if you have a Postman account:

1. You'll need to get the X-Api-Key for your Postman project (on your Postman account), then you'll be able to use Postman API calls to get the collection and environment ids. [Here's the link with Postman API documentation.](https://docs.api.getpostman.com/)
2. Install Newman to your npm. [Here are the details about Newman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman)
3. Run a command line from your bamboo that will trigger the Postman test run.
   The command will look this way:

   newman run https://api.getpostman.com/collections/{{collectionId}}?apikey={{ApiKey}}
   -e https://api.getpostman.com/environments/{{EnvironmentId}}?apikey={{ApiKey}}

Comment: Hi Tamara, Thanks for your reply. It was very useful for me. Running this way is fine if its run in my local system. However I want to run my postman collection in our bamboo CI server which is accessed many in our organisation for running their builds in dev and prod envs. So the above method would expose my postman apikey there and someone could accidentally delete my collection. Please let me know if there is a  way to hide these keys in bamboo!